# Iterate many collections in sequence vs getting each one asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Given these two approaches I was wondering what are the pros and cons of each one.

a)

```
        var aList = aContainer.ListAsync();
        var bList = bContainer.ListAsync();
        Task.WaitAll(aList, bList);
        return new Item[0].Union(aList.Result).Union(bList.Result).
            Select(x => Transform(x));
```

vs

b)

```
        var aList = aContainer.List();
        var bList = bContainer.List();
        return new Item[0].Union(aList).Union(bList).
            Select(x => Transform(x));
```

My findings:

- with a) I have parallel execution but I can't chain in a functional programming way (like it's done in b)
- with b) I get iterator behaviour but I have to wait for each collection to be calculated (in the exact same order that they were coded, bList can't be calculated until aList finished)

Some points to take into account:

- ListAsync returns `Task<List<A>>` (does it make sense to return `Task<IEnumerable<A>>`?)
- List returns `IEnumerable<A>`

Comment: What chaining aren't you getting with (a)? To your edit, b is effectively the same at the end (albeit without the extra `.Result`). Please clarify further.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET , the results are the same but there's a significant difference between a and b. In b the execution is deferred until the first Union statement and both enumerables are iterated just once each. While in a, by the time it's executed, both collections were populated and both were iterated twice

Comment: I don't doubt they execute differently, I'm just trying to figure out what you are getting at with the "chaining" comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this "chaining" difference you mention. The primary difference is one gets both items asynchronously (then synchronously blocks to wait!) and the other gets each item one at a time.

So I would go with (a) every time. I would additionally change it to await all of them so the thread doesn't block. Switching (a) to use `IEnumerable` instead of `List` will likely also save you a few enumerations, so is probably worthwhile.

Comment: I tried to generalize a particular case I working with. The real thing is: I have to merge 2 query results and ideally I'd like to execute them both in parallel leaving the merge for the end.

Comment: @PatoLoco Sure. And I agree that you should do that. Is that not clear in my answer?